# How to obtain a smaller-sized output from Solve

Tags: programming, functions

I am solving a system of 15 simultaneous linear equations using `Solve`. On running the code, I get a message saying "A very large output was generated" with options for viewing the ouput. I want to use the solution inside a larger program where the next step relies on the ouput of `Solve`. I am stuck unless there is a reasonable way for me to capture the output from `Solve`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You don't need to display the output; if you do `sol = Solve[...];` you'll suppress the output (with `;`) but everything will be assigned to `sol`.

Comment: If you have not already done so, set Cubics->False and Quartics->False and see if that improves matters.

Comment: Because these are *linear* equations, why aren't you using [LinearSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearSolve.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this useful?

```
s1 = Solve[Table[RandomInteger[100, {15}]. Array[x, 15] == y@i, {i, 15}], Array[y, 15]];
y[1] /. s1[[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. I first put the set of equations as a `SparseArray` using `CoefficientArrays` function. Then solved using `LinearSolve`.

```
{b,m}=CoefficientArrays[Set of Equations, {Variable List}];
LinearSolve[m,-b]
```

See the tutorial ["Solving Linear Systems"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SolvingLinearSystems.html) (I have version 8)

Comment: Ah, I missed "linear". That being the case you might also want to experiment with options Method->OneStepRowReduction or DivisionFreeRowReduction.